# Homeomorphism over it's image takes open sets to open sets in respect to what set?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $M \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$, and suppose $f: U \subseteq \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ is an homeomorphism over it's image $f(U) \subseteq M$, where $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Let $U_0 \subseteq U$ be another open set of $\mathbb{R^n}$. Is $f(U_0)$ an open set of $\mathbb{R^n}$? Is it open in $M$? And in $f(U)$?

I'm a little bit confused on where the image of open sets are open in this case. My judge is that it's open in $f(U)$, but i was hoping it's also open in $\mathbb{R^n}$. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The fact $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ makes the ambiguous term "open" unambiguous: an open subset of $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Moreover, if $f$ is an homeomorphism, $f(U)$ is also an open subset, and the same reasoning works here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a given homeomorphism onto image $f:X\to Y$ we have that $f(V)$ is always open in the full image $f(X)$. However it doesn't have to be open in $Y$ in general, because the full image $f(X)$ is not necessarily an open subset of $Y$.

But in the special case $f:U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ with $U$ open we have that the image (of any open subset) indeed is open by [the invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) which is a highly nontrivial theorem.

Comment: +1. To the OP, re: the first sentence, the key point is that a homeomorphism has a continuous inverse so the image of an open sets is open. (Also I love the phrase "highly nontrivial" - that might be my favorite silly common phrase in mathematics.)